# Integer precision with python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

When the length of a big integer exceeds 15, the last digits are set to 0. How can I avoid this? For example,

```
a=[1,100,20,167,52,96,181,0]
b = 0
for i in range(8):
    b = b + a[i]*(2**(8*(i)))
    print a[i]
print "%f" % b
```

`b` is 51052750042326016, however, the actual value should be 51052750042326017.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Floating Point Limitations](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) page:

> On a typical machine running Python, there are 53 bits of precision
>   available for a Python float

As such:

```
>>> a = 2 ** 53 + 1
>>> a
9007199254740993L
>>> int(float(a))
9007199254740992L
```

In your example above, by using the format `%f` in your `print`, you're implicitly converting the integer `b` to a float. Since its magnitude is greater than what can be represented exactly as a float in Python, it is given the closest possible 53-bit representation.

The simplest way to avoid that is to print the integer *as* an integer, with the format `%d`.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `b` is assigned to an integer, not a float type, so you could use `"%d"` format to print it. Float values have this [issue and limitation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) as they are represented in computer hardware as base 2 (binary) fractions:

```
a=[1,100,20,167,52,96,181,0]
b = 0
for i in range(8):
    b = b + a[i]*(2**(8*(i)))
    print a[i]
print "%d" % b
```

Output of `print "%d %f" % (b, b)`:

```
51052750042326017 51052750042326016.000000
```

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html):

> Unfortunately, most decimal fractions cannot be represented exactly as
>   binary fractions. A consequence is that, in general, the decimal
>   floating-point numbers you enter are only approximated by the binary
>   floating-point numbers actually stored in the machine.